# What is the right way to typeset these limits?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, formatting, typesetting

In [a recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/582060/25554) I typeset the following expression:

$$\cos x\left.\right|_{-\pi/4}^0$$

(I used `\cos x\left.\right|_{-\pi/4}^0`)

I thought it looked funny on the page, but I wasn't sure it would look funny to anyone else, and I couldn't articulate to myself what about it looked bad. I think it has something to do with the way the lower limit sticks out.  But I'm sure that using `\frac\pi4` there instead would be much worse.

**Clarification**: I don't think MathJax is the culprit here; I think it did just what I asked for.  **My question is whether I asked for the right thing**, in the same sense that $\cos x\left.\right|_{-\pi/4}^0$ is closer to the right thing than $\cos x\left.\right|_{-\frac\pi4}^0$ is.

Does anyone have any thoughts about this?

Comment: Can you provide a link please?

Comment: Yes, but it occurs to me that I may not have made my question clear. I am not suggesting that MathJax messed up here; I'm asking how I should tell MathJax to typeset this kind of expression.

Comment: This doesn't address the main question (placement of limits) but it might be better to use \left[ and \right] for these expressions, in terms of both typesetting and clarity.  Using a \right something without a \left of the same thing is abusive, in my opinion.

Comment: The folks at tex.stackexchange.com may have some useful opinions on this. In my experience they have a good eye for aesthetics as well as technical correctness.

Answer (score 4):

Does this look better?

$$\cos x\Big|^{\kern{.4em}0}_{\raise{-1ex}{\kern{-.3em}-\pi/4}}$$

Comment: No, in my opinion it's much worse.

Comment: Why?$\vphantom{filler}$

Comment: The $\frac\pi4$ is too small and hangs down too low.

Comment: Fine, then. What about now?

Comment: I'm not sure; I've been looking at these too long. What do you think?

Comment: I don't know. I've got the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

In extreme cases like this, I think it is okay to be a bit hackish. You could make the bar taller and space the $0$ out a bit further:
$$
\cos(x)\Big|_{-\pi/4}^{\ \ \ \ 0}
$$
using `\cos(x)\Big|_{-\pi/4}^{\ \ \ \ 0}`.

A bit less hackish is
$$
\cos(x)\Big|_{-\pi/4}^{\hphantom{-}0}
$$
using `\cos(x)\Big|_{-\pi/4}^{\hphantom{-}0}`.

Comment: That huge space before the $0$ looks very strange to me.

Comment: @dfeuer: you can adjust the number of spaces to fit your taste. I had thought the OP did not like the look with no added space.

Answer (score 1):

I had to check what you meant. In these parts we use a totally different notation. May be limited to a small geographic area?

$$\mathop{\Big/}\nolimits_{\hspace{-2mm}-\pi/4}^{\hspace{1mm}0}\cos x$$

Needs a bit of hacking for the spacing look good. That slash should have the same slope as the integral sign. At least that's how it was typeset in my old (=pre-TeX) high school books:
$$
\int_{-\pi/4}^0(-\sin x)\,dx=\mathop{\Big/}\nolimits_{\hspace{-2mm}-\pi/4}^{\hspace{1mm}0}\cos x
$$
so both the slope and height of that slash are a bit wrong here IMHO.

Somehow I thought that (what I learned last night while searching the net) that it is just author's choice of notation, but your way of having that vertical line **after** the function seems to be nearly universal?? Wonder how I avoided learning about this while in grad school. I guess I never had to calculate a definite integral on the chalk board :-).

Sorry about veering off-topic. This just puzzles me.

Comment: This managed to collect an undelete vote, so I let it be visible to all. I asked colleagues who are currently writing a calculus textbook, and they confided to me to using hacks liks the above. Also you need to define separate macros for display and in-line modes.

Answer (score 1):

Your original code abuses left and right rather horribly. The logically correct way to use them would be
$$\left.\cos x\right|_{-\pi/4}^0,$$
`\left.\cos x\right|_{-\pi/4}^0`, which gives the same bad result you started with but at least makes sense. Since you don't like it, let's try a very slight modification:
$$\cos x\hskip 0.03em\bigr|_{-\pi/4}^0,$$
`\cos x\hskip 0.03em\bigr|_{-\pi/4}^0`. How do you like that version?

Comment: That wasn't intentional abuse; it was just a mistake.  Had someone asked me, I would have said that the `\left.` was before the cosine, not after it.  I'll look at the rest of your reply tomorrow.

Comment: @MJD, everyone makes mistakes. The reason I think it may make sense to add a bit of space before the bar (less than `\,`, but perhaps a tiny drop more than I put) is that without it, the bar seems to bind to the $x$ rather than to the whole expression.